# How to add extra value to the Animated Value on Animated.Event?

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation

I'm trying to add new event values to the current ones, instead of replacing them.

This code is replacing `touchX` and `touchY` values with the `translationX` and the `translationX`

```
    Animated.event(
      [
        {
          nativeEvent: {
            translationX: this.touchX,
            translationY: this.touchY
          }
        }
      ],
      {
        useNativeDriver: false
      }
    )(event);
```

I've tired achieve it running this code

```
    this.touchX.setValue(
      Animated.add(this.touchX, new Animated.Value(translationX))
    );
    this.touchY.setValue(
      Animated.add(this.touchY, new Animated.Value(translationY))
    );
```

Unfortunetely this one is causing error when trying to apply `touchX` to my Animated component `Transform with key of "translateX" must be a number: {"translateX":"[object Object]0"}`

I expect `touchX` to equal `this.touchX + translationX` after each event.

Answer (score 0):

`Animated.Add()` is returning animated Object and `setValue` is expecting a number in that case.

```
    this.touchX.setValue(this.touchX._value + translationX);
    this.touchY.setValue(this.touchY._value + translationY);
```